# How to decode a nested JSON struct with dynamic number of nested levels?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

I can receive a JSON file with variable number of nested fields, like for example this:

```
{
 "id": "field1",
 "values": [{
  "1": [{ 
    "11": ["111", "112"],
    "12": ["121", "122"]
  }],
  "2": [{ 
    "21": ["211", "212"],
    "22": ["221", "222"]
  }]
]
}
```

so that would be decoded as `[String: [String: [String]]]`

or could be:

```
{
 "id": "field1",
 "values": [{
    "1": ["11", "12"],
    "2": ["21", "22"]
  }]
}
```

so it would de decoded as `[String: [String]]`, or could have one with even more nested levels (`[String: [String: [String: [String]]]]`)... but I don´t know the structure I will receive in beforehand.

Is it possible to handle this scenario?

Comment: The JSON you added is not in the correct format.

Comment: How would you use such `values` in your code base once parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Codable`** to get that working.

**Model:**

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let id: String
    let values: [[String:[[String:[String]]]]]
}
```

**Parsing** goes like,

```
do{
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The above code is a straight-forward parsing of any number of nested levels. Any specific model architecture will depend upon how are you using the model.